# How to solve this error in nextjs with images showing Error: Objects are not valid as React child

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I have to use the cloudinary in my nextjs web I am trying to get multiple images but after clicking on the submit is shows me error that **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. ** How should I overcome from this problem. This code is working if i selects only one image but when i try to select more than one image it will give me errors.

The Front End part is = *in front end "use client" and export default is used.

```
const AdminComp = () => {
   
    const {user, setUser} = useContext(Context);
    if(!user._id) return redirect("/login");
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [skills, setSkills] = useState({});
    const [about, setAbout] = useState({});


    const submitHandler = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/admin/update", {
          method:"PUT",
          headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({
            name, email, password, about, skills
          })
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        if(!data.success) return toast.error(data.message);
        toast.success(data.message);
        
      } catch (error) {
        return toast.error(error);
      }

        
    }

    const handleImages = (e, val) => {
        
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const Reader = new FileReader();

        Reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        Reader.onload = () => {
          if(Reader.readyState === 2){
            if(val === 1){
                setSkills({...skills, image1:Reader.result});
            }
            if(val === 2){
                setSkills({...skills, image2:Reader.result});
            }
            if(val === 3){
                setSkills({...skills, image3:Reader.result});
            }
            if(val === 4){
                setSkills({...skills, image4:Reader.result});
            }
            if(val === 5){
                setSkills({...skills, image5:Reader.result});
            }
            if(val === 6){
                setSkills({...skills, image6:Reader.result});
            }
          
          }
        }

        



    }

    const handleAboutImage = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const Reader = new FileReader();
        Reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        Reader.onload = () => {
          if(Reader.readyState === 2){
            setAbout({...about, avatar:Reader.result});
          }
        }

        alert("Image About Updated.");
    }


    const logoutHandler = async() => {

      try {

        const res = await fetch("/api/auth/logout");
        const data = await res.json();
        if(!data.success) return toast.error(data.message);
        setUser({});
        toast.success(data.message);
        
      } catch (error) {
        return toast.error(error);
      }
      
        alert("Logout Successfully.");
        if(!user._id) return redirect("/login");

    }

  return (
    <>
        <Typography variant="h4">
          <p>A</p>
          <p>D</p>
          <p>M</p>
          <p>I</p>
          <p style={{ marginRight: "1vmax" }}>N</p>

          <p>P</p>
          <p>A</p>
          <p>N</p>
          <p>E</p>
          <p>L</p>
        </Typography>

        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            className="adminPanelInputs"
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            className="adminPanelInputs"
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            className="adminPanelInputs"
          />

          <div className="adminPanelSkill">
            <div>
              <Typography>SKILL 1</Typography>
              <input
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleImages(e, 1)}
                accept="image/*"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Typography>SKILL 2</Typography>

              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleImages(e, 2)}
                accept="image/*"
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Typography>SKILL 3</Typography>

              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleImages(e, 3)}
                accept="image/*"
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Typography>SKILL 4</Typography>

              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleImages(e, 4)}
                accept="image/*"
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Typography>SKILL 5</Typography>

              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleImages(e, 5)}
                accept="image/*"
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Typography>SKILL 6</Typography>

              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleImages(e, 6)}
                accept="image/*"
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="adminPanelAbout">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>About</legend>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={about.name}
                onChange={(e) => setAbout({ ...about, name: e.target.value })}
                className="adminPanelInputs"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Title"
                value={about.title}
                onChange={(e) => setAbout({ ...about, title: e.target.value })}
                className="adminPanelInputs"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Subtitle"
                value={about.subtitle}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setAbout({ ...about, subtitle: e.target.value })
                }
                className="adminPanelInputs"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Description"
                value={about.description}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setAbout({ ...about, description: e.target.value })
                }
                className="adminPanelInputs"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Quote"
                value={about.quote}
                onChange={(e) => setAbout({ ...about, quote: e.target.value })}
                className="adminPanelInputs"
              />

              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={handleAboutImage}
                className="adminPanelFileUpload"
                placeholder="Choose Avatar"
                accept="image/*"
              />
            </fieldset>
          </div>

          <Link href={"/admin-panel/timeline"}>
            TIMELINE <MdTimeline />
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/admin-panel/project"}>
            PROJECTS <AiOutlineProject />
          </Link>

          <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
            Update
          </Button>
        </form>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="error"
          style={{ display: "block", margin: "4vmax auto" }}
          onClick={logoutHandler}
        >
          LOGOUT
        </Button>


    </>
  )
}
```

backend Part = exported default

````
const updateUser = asyncError(async(req, res)=>{

    if(req.method!=="PUT") return errorHandler(res, 400, "Only PUT Method Allowed.");
    const {name, email, password, skills, about } = req.body;
    
console.log(skills)
    // if(!_id||!name||!email||password||skills||about)
    //     return errorHandler(res, 400, "User Fields are Empty.");
    
    await connectDB();
    // const user = await checkAuth(req);
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if(!user) return errorHandler(res, 400, "User Not Found.");

    if(name){
        user.name = name;
    }
    if(email){
        user.email = email;
    }
    if(password){
        user.password = password;
    }
    if(about){
        if(about.name){
            user.about.name = about.name;
        }
        if(about.title){
            user.about.title = about.title;
        }
        if(about.subtitle){
            user.about.subtitle = about.subtitle;
        }
        if(about.description){
            user.about.description = about.description;
        }
        if(about.quote){
            user.about.quote = about.quote;
        }
        if(about.avatar){
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(about.avatar, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });

            user.about.avatar = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            }
        }
    }

    if(skills){
        
        if(skills.image1){    
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(skills.image1, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });

            user.skills.image1 = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            };
        }
        if(skills.image2){
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(skills.image2, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });

            user.skills.image2 = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            };
        }
        if(skills.image3){
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(skills.image3, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });

            user.skills.image3 = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            };
        }
        if(skills.image4){
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(skills.image4, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });

            user.skills.image4 = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            };
        }
        if(skills.image5){
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(skills.image5, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });

            user.skills.image5 = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            };
        }
        if(skills.image6){
            cloudinaryConnect();
            const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(skills.image6, {
                folder:"Portfolio"
            });
            // console.log(myCloud);

            user.skills.image6 = {
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            };
        }
    }

    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        message:"User Updated Successfully."
    });

});```



The cloudinary function is =
````

```
export const cloudinaryConnect = () => {
try{
    cloudinary.v2.config({
        cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
        api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
        api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET});
   }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

```
I have tried to do eveything I am expecting that this will work fine and it will not give me any error. 

**error** = 
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXSrr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXSrr.png)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is, but since you have a lot of code here, honestly your debugging strategy should be to remove blocks of code one at a time and simplify your program until the problem stops, and then try to recreate it again.

Comment: My issue is that I have to upload all 6 images to cloudinary at a time but I am unable to do it. if I just select one image and then click on submit button it works fine but not with all images selected.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I wasn’t sure what’s causing your issue because I’m not familiar with cloudinary. But I was trying to offer some debugging advice. For example, perhaps simplify your application to being able to select up to just two images, and see if that makes it easier to find the source of the issue